# EF. Why is dynamicproxies only create for some entites?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework with database first. I have a edmx file with entites, among others Order and Device.

I do the simplest possible queries like this.

```
var o = db.Orders.First();
var d = db.Device.First();
```

If I put a breakpoint after these lines and add a watch to both o and d, I can see that o is of type "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Order_F41BB20DDE174FDA86E0D7716990689D9E5D9260345B31726A97A13750358370", while d is of type "MyNamespace.Device".

Why has not a dynamicproxy been generated for Device?

Since no proxy is generated for Device, lazyloading does not work.

My Device class looks like this:

```
public partial class Device
{
    protected Device()
    {
        this.ActiveLoadingComputers = new HashSet<ActiveLoadingComputer>();
        this.LoadReports = new HashSet<LoadReport>();
    }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LoadingPlace_Id { get; protected set; }

    internal virtual ICollection<ActiveLoadingComputer> ActiveLoadingComputers { get; private set; }
    internal virtual ICollection<LoadReport> LoadReports { get; private set; }
    internal virtual LoadingPlace LoadingPlace { get; private set; }
}
```

and it also have another partial definition.

```
public partial class Device
{
    public Device(string name) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do both classes meet the Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: colin promote to answer please. a property isnt virtual  or other requirement  is missing.

Comment: I've updated my question with the Device class. I can't figure out which requirements isn't met.

Comment: @ErikZ: None of your mapped properties on the `Device` class are `virtual`, and none of your navigation properties are `public`. That violates the first requirement listed under change tracking proxies, and the single requirement under lazy loading proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to private specifier for set accessor of navigation properties.

Comment: I don't think so, see my own answer.

Comment: So you don't think that problem was with private setters and just by accident changed yours setter to protected and voila now thing works and you have answered you own question? Very funny.

Comment: Ofcourse is it that change that made the difference, but what I mean is that I can have the other two navigationproperties(look at LoadReports and ActiveLoadingComputers) setters as private. Isn't that strange?

Comment: Nope it just means that 2 other properties still will not be proxied and lazy load will not work for them.

Comment: Ok, that's probably correct, but my that wasn't my problem. My problem was that my class(Device) CONTAINING the navigation properties didn't get proxied. After changing only one of the navigation properties the Device class get proxied. The other two still has private setters, thats why I did not mark your answer as correct.

Comment: So you still don't understand how proxy is working. Imagine if you have to do it yourself:
1. Is it possible to replace navigation property even if its virtual but with private setter with you own implementation that support lazy load?
2. Is it good idea to proxy(override) object if you can't override any of its properties?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't grasped this. :) You're absolutely correct. We need at least on navigation property for EF to think it's any point to create a proxy. That makes sense. If I only have one public property thats is enough. And as you pointed out it's only the public property thats get lazyloaded. I had to do some testing to realize that. Thank you for being so patient. I'll mark your answer as correct. :)